# 301 Redirect dynamic urls from database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, http-status-code-301, global-asax

I have thousands of `links` which need to be `redirect` to `new URL` using `301 Permanent Redirect`. I have all these `urls` in the Database table. I would like to know where should be these URLs should be loaded (only once). And can be used for **301 permanent redirect.**

**Sample URLs:**

```
*RequestForURL*                                                             *301Redirect*


why-me/onboard-experience/food-and-drink-for-all-tastes/family-casual/->    /why-me/family-test/
    why-me/onboard-experience/food-and-drink-for-all-tastes/room-service/-> /why-me/onboard-experience/food-for-all-tastes/
    why-me/onboard-experience/food-and-drink-for-all-tastes/specialist-restaurants/->   /why-me/onboard-experience/food-for-all-tastes/
    why-me/onboard-experience/food-for-all-tastes/me-deals/->   /why-me/onboard-experience/
    why-me/onboard-experience/food-for-all-tastes/me-deals/wowsale2013.aspx /why-me/onboard-experience/
    why-me/onboard-experience/food-for-all-tastes/dining-packages/->    /why-me/onboard-experience/food-for-all-tastes/
    why-me/onboard-experience/food-for-all-tastes/drinks-packages/->    /why-me/onboard-experience/dazzling-entertainment/drink-packages/
    why-me/onboard-experience/food-for-all-tastes/family-casual/->  /why-me/onboard-experience/food-for-all-tastes/
    why-me/onboard-experience/food-for-all-tastes/room-service/ /why-me/onboard-experience/food-for-all-tastes/
    why-me/onboard-experience/food-for-all-tastes/speciality-dining/->  /why-me/onboard-experience/food-for-all-tastes/
    why-me/onboard-experience/types-of-me/->    /why-me/onboard-experience/
```

**I am using VS 2013 Framework 4.0**

**NOTE:** *Data must be loaded once only into Session or during first application request.*

Answer (score 0):

Load the values from the database in `Application_Start` into a static `Dictionary<string, string>`, then check the requested URL in `BeginRequest` to see if it's key exists in a redirect dictionary, then do `context.Response.RedirectPermanent(value)` if it does.