# Is it a good practice to use `Response.Redirect()` in `Global.asax`

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am getting runtime exception on use of **`Response.Redirect()`** in `global.asax`

Results in:

*HttpException: Response is not available in this context.*

I tried using,

**`HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect()`**

Results in:

*NullReferenceExeption: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

---

I know that the basic purpose of Global.asax is to handle,

1. Application level events
2. Session-level events

But my fundamental question is, Is it a good practice to use `Response.Redirect()` in `Global.asax` file.. ?

Comment: Why do you have to use it in global.asax?

Comment: @Manu, Because some session variables are handled in global.asax.

Comment: can u put Global.asax code here?

Comment: i also used to handle exceptions in Application_Error event and redirect to custom error page and in background sending exception log to support email address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Response.Redirect` in Global.asax assuming you are doing in events that have request (like begin request).

You definitely can't use Request during application level events because there is no `HttpRequest.Current` available.

Note that while there nothing particularly wrong about having such code in Global.asax, usually such redirect code put into Modules (i.e authentication frequently done as HttpModule and there are plenty redirects), Forms (WebForms) or Controllers (MVC), action attributes (MVC).

Answer (score 2):

It's not good or bad practice in particular. What are you actually trying to do? You've provided one line of code without any context whatsoever. Are you trying to redirect certain requests similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119219), or something else?

The reason you're getting that exception is, not surprisingly, because there is no request context available as the code is running before `Begin_Request`.

Comment: yes, I was trying to redirect to some another page is Session_End() event.